# bootstrap tables only horizontal dividers not applying

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am calling a json script that fills my table which works fine. I am simply trying to make it with just horizontal dividers only and according to [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables) a should just have to add `class="table"` to my `<table>` yet it takes no effect. Do I have to do this through my jQuery code?

**jquery**

```
$('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 600,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    pageList: [20, 40, 60, 100, 200],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'title',
        title: 'Title',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'audio',
        title: 'Audio',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet1',
        title: 'Sheet 1',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet2',
        title: 'Sheet 2',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet3',
        title: 'Sheet 3',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'lyrics',
        title: 'Lyrics',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet1notes',
        title: 'Notes 1',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet2notes',
        title: 'Notes 2',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    },{
        field: 'sheet3notes',
        title: 'Notes 3',
        align: 'center',
        sortable: true
    }]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Music</h1>
            <table id="table-javascript" class="table"></table>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set classes option to table table-no-bordered. Look at this example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/no-bordered.html.